# Merge entries in Map without using loop in scala

Tags: scala, maps

Could someone suggest a best way to merge entries in map for below use case in scala (possibly without using loop)?

**From**

```
val map1 = Map(((1,"case0")->List(1,2,3)), ((2,"case0")->List(3,4,5)), ((1,"case1")->List(2,4,6)), ((2,"case1")->List(3)))
```

**To**

```
Map(((1,"nocase")->List(2)), ((2,"nocase")->List(3)))
```

Comment: How come you have Duplicate keys in a Map. Did you tried printing this map? It'll display/store latest keys only.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Key is a tuple in my case. Edited the question.

Comment: Now you have to update your result also according to your key

Comment: @Learner yes. This is possible using a for loop. However I wanted to know if this can be achieved using flatMap or groupBy etc.,

Comment: how is the input related to the expected output?

Comment: On what basis are you trying to merge the input to get output?

Comment: Merge is always based on first element in the key tuple. i.e., keys (1, 'case0') and (1,'case1') are merged based on key._1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
map1.groupBy(_._1._1).map{case (key, elements) => ((key, "nocase"), elements.values.reduce(_ intersect _ ))}
```

With the group you group the elements by the first element of the key, then with the map, you build the new key, with the "nocase" string as in your example. With elements.value you get all the elements for the given keys and you can reduce them with the intersect you get the expected output

Output:

```
Map[(Int, String),List[Int]] = Map((2,nocase) -> List(3), (1,nocase) -> List(2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Curious to know if grouping can be done only for specific keys which matches a condition and not for all keys? Also instead of "nocase" in the above question, if I have to use either of "case0" or "case1" from the actual key, is it possible to achieve?

Comment: If you want to join by the whole key, you can do it just modifying the groupBy:

map1.groupBy(_._1).map{case (key, elements) => (key, elements.values.reduce(_ intersect _ ))}

Comment: Using ._1 would still apply grouping for all keys, but I wanted to exclude this grouping for certain keys.

Comment: Umm, i don't know if its possible to join only by certain keys. What you can do is join as is, and then filter out the undesired keys. But I don't know if that match your requirement

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.